# Bootstrap 3 Tabs Not Displaying properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok So I am in the middle of putting together my page on my website for my services that I provide and once i update my code I realize my tabs are not Displaying properly.... and I dont understand exactly whats the problem. I dont see any problem in my code. But Instead of the Divs inside the container displaying at the very top of the container they are in the position that they are in-line or where the code is on the page..... 
i need each individual tabs content to display at the top of the page

HEres a Example /

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgLxyZ

or you can visit my website and check out the live version 
http://www.trillumonopoly.com

**and visit the "Services" Link In the NavBar. The Active Tab displays properly but non of the other ones do**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!--SLIDER-->
    <div class="well" style=" border-radius:5px; border-bottom-color:Silver; border:3px; border-top-color: transparent !important; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8)">
        <img src="../images/banner1.jpg" width="100%" alt=""><br>
        GOOGLE AD HERE

    </div>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid" style=" border-radius:5px; border-bottom-color:Silver; border:3px; border-top-color: transparent !important; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8)">
     <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#GFX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
               GFX DESIGN
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#MUSICDISTRIBUTION" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          Music Distribution
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#VIDEODISTRIBUTION" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          Video Distribution
          </a>
      </li>
       <li><a href="#WEBDEVELOPMENT" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
           Web Development
          </a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#PROMOTIONS" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
           Promotions
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ADVERTISEMENTS" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
           Advertisements
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#RadioCampaigns" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
           Radio Campaigns
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#SongMastering" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
           Song Mastering
          </a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content container-fluid"><center>
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="GFX"> 
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> 
          CD COVER DESIGN SINGLE  <br> 
          <img src="images/CDCover.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
          <br>  <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button<br>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> CD COVER DESIGN DOUBLE  <br> <img src="images/doublecd.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br><b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> FULL ALBUM ARTWORK <br> <img src="images/fullAlbum.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br>  <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> FLYER DESIGN SINGLE <br> <img src="images/flyerDesign.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> FLYER DESIGN DOUBLE <br> <img src="images/flyerDesign.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br>   </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BUSINESS CARD DESIGN SINGLE  <br> <img src="images/bizCards.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BUSINESS CARD DESIGN DOUBLE  <br> <img src="images/bizCards.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> POSTER DESIGN (ALL SIZES) <br> <img src="images/poster.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BROCHURE DESIGN <br> <img src="images/brochure.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> WEB BANNER (ALL SIZES) <br> <img src="images/webBanner.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BANNER (ALL SIZES) <br> <img src="images/banners.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> 2D LOGO DESIGN  <br> <img src="images/2dLogo.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> 3D LOGO DESIGN <br> <img src="images/3dlogo.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> TICKET DESIGN <br> <img src="images/tickets.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BOOK COVER <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> CUSTOM PRODUCT PACKAGING <br> <img src="images/concepts.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> BUY BUTTON </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="MUSICDISTRIBUTION">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">   </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Streaming Media Pkg  <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> GOLD ARTIST Pkg <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> PLATINUM ARTIST Pkg <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> LABEL PKG <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> HELLA UNITS PKG (Physical Distribution) <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="VIDEODISTRIBUTION">

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> VEVO CHANNEL<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button   </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> MTV NETWORK<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> REVOLT <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BET NETWORK<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> MUSIC CHOICE <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> FUSE<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="WEBDEVELOPMENT">

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">  ONE PAGE WEBPAGE <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">  FULL WEBSITE<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">  TWITTER<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">  TUMBLR<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">  FACEBOOK <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button </div>

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="PROMOTIONS">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> TWITTER <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> FACEBOOK<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> INSTAGRAM <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> YOUTUBE<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> EMAIL BLAST<br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button </div>

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ADVERTISEMENTS">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BANNERS <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> BILLBOARDS <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button   </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> MAGAZINE <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> WEBSITES <br> PICTURE <br> <b><font color="orange">Price:</font></b> $50 (USD) <br><b><font color="orange">TurnAround:</font></b> 24-48 HRS w/ Proof <br><b><font color="orange">Description:</font></b> WE CUSTOM DESIGN THE FRONT OF YOUR NEXT CD/MIXTAPE COVER. DESIGNED TO YOUR SPECIFICATIONS OR HAVE ONE OF OUR SPECIALIST PROVIDE YOU WITH UNDENIABLE HIGH QUALITY DESIGN THAT BEST SUITS YOUR PRODUCT, BRAND OR IMAGE<br><b><font color="orange">Options:</font></b> For Extra $15(US) Get PSD file for Later Editing.  <br> Buy Button  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="RadioCampaigns">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> RADIO ADS <br> </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> GOLD PKG <br> </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> PLATINUM PKG <br></div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> DIAMOND PKG </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> TAKEOVER PKG </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="SongMastering">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">   </div>

    </div></center>
 </div>   <br><br>
</div>
```

Please help me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Get the tabs out of the colored div? If that is so you could apply your inline style to the tab-content div, that leaves out tabs from content box and they still work

Comment: @jonathanxxi I am trying to get the content inside of the tabs to display at the top of the container instead of having to scroll half way done the page filled with no content just to see other content from the other divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<center>` and `</center>` encasing your tab content.  Here is a working codepen.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QymZQV)

If you want to center text using bootstrap just use the class text-center.  So in your tab content div just add the class text-center